# How to filter some combinations from being generated in product function of itertools of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, generator, python-itertools

> I'm working on a some kind of password generated some sort of program, using the `itertools` module of the python, with its `product` function i'm trying to generate *unique* passwords that are **NOT** already saved in the database i'm having.

The problem is:
When i'm trying to generate more passwords, i need to wait a hell of a time! for the new password to come out, i've already written the code to filter the passwords that are already within the database **BUT** the `product` function **STILL** processes the passwords EVEN if they are already used, then it prints out the passwords that aren't used already which still takes the same amount of time which is just too much!
Now i know that i could use my GPU for this process, but i'm sure there's gotta be a logical operation to stop this function from generating the already used passwords.

Here's the source code
(don't pay too much attention to the other parts of the code, i know it doesn't work by itself because i'm using this `Generator` function in another kind of master main program):

```
from string import *
from itertools import product

# The password generator function.
# a little detail about the parameters:
# From = password starts from how many characters
# To = password ends with how many characters
# Fname = stands for 'file name' which is actually the database name
# cn, Base = these are just to organize different databases, not too much important in this case
def Generator(From, To, Fname, cn, Base):
    # Defining the database
    global db
    db = Fname+cn+'.txt'
    # Listing all the already used passwords in the 'lines' list
    global lines
    lines = []
    mainDB = open(Fname+str(Base)+'.txt')
    lines = mainDB.readlines()
    mainDB.close()
    # Defining the characters which (probably) can't be used as passwords(due to injection attacks and so on...)
    Blocked = ",:?/\\|<>*"+"'"+'"'
    # The ones that i'm not sure if they have to be blocked... but i'm blocking them anyway :|
    proBlocked = ";[]{}()+=^`"
    Blocked += proBlocked
    chars = ascii_letters + digits + punctuation
    # Deleting all the blocked characters from the main 'chars' string
    for c in Blocked:
        chars = chars.replace(c,'')

    # Going for generating the password trying every single password we can make and take a unique one out for use
    for i in range(From,To):
        # Starting the `product` module which is the main element of the program
        for j in product(chars, repeat=i):
            # Defining the 'word' container(or the 'password' container if you will)
            global word
            # Putting the generated word in the container(variable)
            word = "".join(j)
            # Opening the database
            p = open(db, '+r')
            # Checking if the password has already been used and added to the main database
            if not(word in str(lines)):
                # Adding to the database and returning the unique password
                p.write(p.read() + word + '\n')
                p.close()
                return word
```

Here's the main program:

```
from Generator import Generator
import os
import sys

# This part needs some more work, like designing and so on
# right now we're just testing.
while True:
    os.system('cls')
    inp = input("Type 1 to start generating, or type 0 to close the program:\n")
    if inp.isdigit():
        if inp == '1':
            break
        elif inp == '0':
            sys.exit()

print("Here's your unique password: "+Generator(4, 10, "MainDB", 1, 1))
```

This is how the program's output looks like:

```
Type 1 to start generating, or type 0 to close the program:
1
Here's your unique password: aaaa
```

Now by filtering more passwords within the database, the passwords wouldn't be things like 'aaaa' and they'll be nicer and sometimes mean something and can be remembered (instead of using random though cause i already have a program for that one)

Really appreciate your help <3
again, the problem is: i'm looking for a way to filter the already used password IN the product module ITSELF to stop those from being EVEN generated to save a lot of time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If they are supposed to be passwords, then I would expect them to be generated randomly, not in sequence... ??

Comment: It's really hard to understand the question here. Can you provide some working code that illustrates the problem you are having? Perhaps a clear description of what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah of course, but i've already made a similar program and just wanted to make another one with this kind of method

Comment: well i've already explained it... but sure, how you wanna me to do that?

Comment: Are you attempting to generate a password or are you attempting to crack a password? This is not the way to go to generate one. A solution based on random.choice() is rather straightforward if what you seek to do is generate a password.

Comment: Yea ye ye i know random could help more with that, my idea was to create a bit more complicated password generator, and just make it kinda better than my previous program that just gives random characters as the passwords, if you know a solution on how to make that `product` module not to process all the already been used passwords all over again, i rlly appreciate your help, btw i just put more details on the question, i hope it helps

Comment: Opening and closing the file, and doing `if not(word in str(lines))` on every iteration of the inner loop will be somewhat expensive. (1) Turn lines into a set rather than a list. (2) Then the check should be `if word not in lines` . No need to convert it to `str(lines)`: this will be slowing your code down.

Comment: hmmm.. ok i'm gonna try that as well, although i don't think if it's also gonna stop the `product` module from keep processing the not needed passwords too

Comment: Ok so i found out i *actually* need to turn lines into a string, or it's not gonna figure out that if word is in lines, so i turned it to a `str` **outside** the loop, will that be good enough? @slothrop

Comment: It's better than converting it to a `str` every time inside the loop, but checking whether the password is in a large concatenated string will be slower than checking whether it is in a set. When you say *"it's not gonna figure out that if word is in lines"* - why is that? Do you need to strip out `\n` and so on from the result of `readlines()` ?

Comment: *"i don't think if it's also gonna stop the product module from keep processing the not needed passwords too"* no, but nothing is going to do that. Even if you wrote your own replacement for `product`, then "not processing the not needed passwords" would boil down to checking the values against some set of used passwords.

Comment: Ok got it, so bad it's possibly never gonna work on `product` function, about that `str` thing, now that u mentioned, i think that's what i have to do, to remove all the `\n`s

Comment: Ok COOL! it worked! so i guess now all i can do to make it faster is to run it on the GPU? u know, using numba perhaps? so do you have no other tips to make it even faster?

Comment: GPUs and numba are more about numerical processing, so unfortunately they're not a natural fit for this problem. Do you expect to use this function many times in the same program? If so, one source of inefficiency is that it starts over every time you call it. If you're going to call it multiple times, you could make it a real generator by using `yield word` rather than `return word`. Then you can instantiate it once and use `next()` to get the next password.

Comment: well i'm not be looping the function itself because it already has a loop in it looking for a unique password. With that being said, u think i still need to use that `yield` and `next()` in order to make it faster? can u answer to the question here and just give an entire example just o wrap it all up and reach to a conclusion?

Comment: So let's say you call the function, it starts iterating at `aaaaa` and finally gets a good password like `a8~!gzy`. If you call it again, it has to repeat that whole iteration, starting at `aaaaa`, until it finds the next good password. If you made it a generator that yielded, it could pick up where it left off. But if you only make one password per run of the program, that's not really a consideration.

Comment: Hey btw! thx dude it's already made my program A LOOOOTTTT FATSER!!! it's even kinda skipped the thing i wanted to! idk how but the logs show that it has!

Comment: Awesome! Wrapped it up in an answer (with a few more cleanups, but using the set is the biggest optimisation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Filtering out the already used passwords" really comes down to checking the output of the `product` function against some set of used passwords. (Even if you wrote your own special "product_with_exclusions" function, it would need to work that way.)

Your code already does this checking, but it can be made faster. On every iteration of the loop over the results of `product`, your code in the question turns the list of passwords into a string and checks the output against that. Repeatedly converting list -> str and checking whether the password is part of that big string is slow. It's better to (1) not do the conversion to str, (2) instead of a `list`, use a `set` (it's much quicker to check whether a value is in a large set, compared to the same-size list).

With that, the optimised code could look something like this. (This includes a few other tidyups - removed unnecessary globals, used with-blocks when opening files, and wrote the new password in append mode.)

```
from string import *
from itertools import product

# The password generator function.
# a little detail about the parameters:
# From = password starts from how many characters
# To = password ends with how many characters
# Fname = stands for 'file name' which is actually the database name
# cn, Base = these are just to organize different databases, not too much important in this case
def Generator(From, To, Fname, cn, Base):
    # Defining the database
    db = Fname+cn+'.txt'
    
    # Listing all the already used passwords in the 'lines_set' set for fast lookup
    with open(Fname+str(Base)+'.txt') as mainDB:
        lines_set = {l.strip() for l in mainDB.readlines()}

    # Defining the characters which (probably) can't be used as passwords(due to injection attacks and so on...)
    Blocked = ",:?/\\|<>*"+"'"+'"'
    
    # The ones that i'm not sure if they have to be blocked... but i'm blocking them anyway :|
    proBlocked = ";[]{}()+=^`"
    Blocked += proBlocked
    chars = ascii_letters + digits + punctuation
    
    # Deleting all the blocked characters from the main 'chars' string
    chars = [c for c in chars if c not in Blocked]

    # Going for generating the password trying every single password we can make and take a unique one out for use
    for i in range(From,To):
        # Starting the `product` module which is the main element of the program
        for j in product(chars, repeat=i):
            # Putting the generated word in the container(variable)
            word = "".join(j)

            # Checking if the password has already been used and added to the main database
            if word not in lines_set:
                # Adding to the database and returning the unique password
                with open(db, 'a') as p: # Open in append mode so we just write one new line
                    p.write(word + '\n')
                return word
```

Comment: The best answer i've ever got for my question! :D i'm gonna make a cleaned-up code of the project tomorrow and post it right here, thx a bunch dude! big big big time!

Answer (score 0):

This is out the output looks like:

```
Type 1 to start generating, or type 0 to close the program:
1
agGM
Here's your unique password: agGM
```

Took only 0.001ms!!! massively fast, so so so cool!!!
a BIIIIGGGG thx to @slothrop !

i cleaned up the main code a little:

```
from Generator import Generator
import os
import sys

while True:
    os.system('cls')
    inp = input("Type 1 to start generating, or type 0 to close the program:\n")
    if inp.isdigit():
        if inp == '1':
            break
        elif inp == '0':
            sys.exit()
gen = Generator(4, 10, "MainDB", '1', 1)
db = open("MainDB1.txt")
lines = set(db.readlines())
pwd = ''
for x in gen:
    print(x)
    if x not in lines:
        pwd = x
        break
print("Here's your unique password: "+pwd)
```

And the function file:

```
from string import *
from itertools import product

def Generator(From, To, Fname, cn, Base):
    db = 'MainDB1.txt'
    p = open(db, '+r')
    lines = []
    mainDB = open('MainDB1.txt', '+r')
    for x in mainDB.readlines():
        lines.append(x.replace('\n', ''))
    mainDB.close()
    lines = set(lines)
    Blocked = ",:?/\\|<>*"+"'"+'"'
    proBlocked = ";[]{}()+=^`"
    Blocked += proBlocked
    chars = ascii_letters + digits + punctuation
    for c in Blocked:
        chars = chars.replace(c,'')

    for i in range(From,To):
        for j in product(chars, repeat=i):
            word = "".join(j)
            if word not in lines:
                p.write(p.read() + word + '\n')
                yield word
```

And i gotta say it was really really the best question i received an answer for! the result is much more better than what i was expecting to have!
thx again @slothrop !

Comment: Nice, you made it `yield`, so that will save it from having to start the iteration again for every password.

Comment: u taught me that ;)

Comment: But still, the PC should be kept on, if not, the yield's kind of memory will be restored and it'll start from the aaaa again, u think there's a solution? i say there is but if there isn't, it still works good already

Comment: Not in a super-neat way. But when you start up, you know the last password generated, because it's the last line in your file. So you could: (1) set `From` to the length of the last password, (2) put a `while` loop in that keeps iterating through `product` until that last password is reached. That needs a bit of care because if you change your password rules so that the last password is no longer valid, you get an infinite loop. I suspect it might not save that much time.

Comment: Soooooo i guess that's a kind of dead end, because in the both ways it takes the same time, right? wish there was a tutorial on these

Comment: Hey! today i tested the project once again and guess what! it actually worked EXACTLY like how i wanted! now it starts the generation RIGHT from where it left off the process!!! idk how it's kinda like a magic that now it's working XD but i love it, thx again rlly!